# C++ Timer implementation

Tags: c++, timer, clock

I'm trying to implement a "timer" function in C++ for the program to do *something* after some seconds.
However, I've got unexpected results.

```
short e, sum;
clock_t start;
double duration=0;

for (e=0; e<4; e++) {
    start = clock();
    while (duration < 1) {

        duration = (clock() - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
    cout << duration;
    duration = 0;
    sum += e;
    /* Calculate EPOCH error */
    cout << e;
}
cout << "\n" << e<< "\n";
```

The results I expect are:

- console output every second, followed by e (0,1,2,3)
- at the end of the execution I expect sum to be 0+1+2+3 = 6,

Results obtained:

- console output followed by e, all together when execution finishes
- sum = 6

What I find uncertain is, why do the program prints to console until execution is finished and not every second as expected?

Cheers,

Comment: Buffering, try `std::cout << e << std::endl;` in the loop.

Comment: The question clearly seems to be c++, so why the `c` tag?

Comment: Offtopic, but why the busy loop and not a sleep?

Comment: How do you correlate `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` with your CPU frequency, especially given that it may vary at run-time? Also, why do you think you should see something every second, do you have an RTOS with strong timing guarantees? :)

Comment: Hey all, thanks for responding. One second is arbitrary, I intend to extend this code to STOP or WARN me once X seconds have gone by. @Troy  sleep is not implemented because work will be done meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the output stream isn't flushed during your loop. Actually writing pieces of text to the console is somewhat expensive. Therefore the input is buffered and only written to the console when a flush occurs. Flushing the stream can be accomplished by streaming `std::flush`:

```
    cout << e<<std::flush;
```

`std::endl` will also flush the stream in addition to adding a newline (writing `\n` **might** also do it, but that's not guaranteed).

As a sidenote: you might want to consider adding some sort of seperators between your numbers to make the output readable.

Comment: Notice that moment of flushing is system dependent.
std::flush and std::endl forces flushing so it's ok, but printing out "\n" may clear the buffer but doesn't have to.

Comment: @Yester: Which is why I wrote that it might do it (should probably add more emphasis to that though)

Comment: Thanks for you quick responses and sorry I answer till now. I have followed your suggestion in flushing the streaming and the results are  quite awesome. Never thought about it and at first I yelled at my computer, but seems to make sense now. Thanks again @grizzly